# How to control switching steps when the user click's on the indicator

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper, mat-stepper

I need to add some logic in order to decide whether the user can change the step by clicking the indicator ( the step number ) or not.
I'm trying to find if there's some callback that fires every step change but also lets you prevent changing the step if needed.

thanks

Comment: can you provide your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can control whether to navigate to step or not, by using `[editable]` property on the `mat-tab` element.

```
<mat-stepper linear #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    ...
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" [editable]="isEditable">
    ...
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    ...
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```

In above example, you cannot move to 2nd tab directly if `isEditable` is false.

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dahggu)